# How to count rows of datagridview column which has some specific value in c#

Tags: c#

Hi I have a `DataGridView` which is not bound to a database. I am using that just for insert data to `SQL Server` but before inserting I need the total rows of first second and third column separately, which contain true and false. And i want to count those rows of columns separately which have just true value. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Firstly welcome to SO.  Please take the time to read [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Having done so, please edit your question to give more information, and in particular show us the code you have already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not post any code so there is no way to know how your grid view columns are configured. What you need to do is loop through the rows and test the values of the columns. For example, if your `DataGridView` variable is named *gridView* you could do something like this:

```
int col1Count = 0;
int col2Count = 0;
int col3Count = 0;
bool cellValue;

foreach ( DataGridViewRow row in gridView.Rows )
{
    cellValue = (bool) row.Cells["col1"].Value;
    if ( cellValue )
    {
        ++col1Count;
    }
    cellValue = (bool) row.Cells["col2"].Value;
    if ( cellValue )
    {
        ++col2Count;
    }
    cellValue = (bool) row.Cells["col3"].Value;
    if ( cellValue )
    {
        ++col3Count;
    }
}
```